# Option menu on recyclerview does not display

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-optionsmenu

I create options menu in recyclerview and cardview. the menu works fine. but why the options menu I created in recyclerview is not showing?

[image: on the preview in android studio design he displays]
[image: but, when I run it, the options menu in the recyclerview does not display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY USING POPUP_MENU!**

In my knowledge option menu should be preferred with the menu bar. and for long click use context menu and for Adapter items you should go for pop up menu

try this android document [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Comment: bro, can you check the new code snippet attached @Rizwan atta

Answer (score 1):

here I attach my code snippet

FavoritRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities.FavoriteFragmentDetail;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Helper.AppController;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Model.Favorit;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.R;
import com.shashank.sony.fancydialoglib.FancyAlertDialog;

import java.util.List;


public class FavoritRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavoritRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Favorit> favoritList;

    public FavoritRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Favorit> favoritList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.favoritList = favoritList;
    }

    @Override
    public FavoritRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.favorit_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, context);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FavoritRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Favorit favorit = favoritList.get(position);

        holder.titleIDfav.setText(favorit.getGajiFav());
        holder.lokasiIDfav.setText(favorit.getLokasiFav());
        holder.gajiIDfav.setText(favorit.getGajiFav());

        String img_logoFavUrl = favorit.getImg_logoFav();
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(img_logoFavUrl)
                .apply(new RequestOptions()
//                                .placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
//                                .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).centerCrop().dontAnimate()
//                         .centerCrop(), .crossFade(), .thumbnail(), .dontAnimate(), .dontTransform() BitmapTransformation(.circleCrop())
                )
                .into(holder.img_logoFav);

        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.fav_options_menu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.menu1:
                                //handle menu1 click
                                break;
                            case R.id.menu2:
                                //handle menu2 click
                                break;

//                            case R.id.menu3:
//                                //handle menu3 click
//                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return favoritList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        private ImageView img_logoFav;
        private TextView titleIDfav;
        private TextView lokasiIDfav;
        private TextView gajiIDfav;
        private TextView buttonViewOption;

        private FancyAlertDialog dialog;
        private FancyAlertDialog.Builder fancyAlertDialogBuilder;

        ViewHolder(View itemView, final Context ctx) {
            super(itemView);
            context = ctx;

            img_logoFav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_logoFav);
            titleIDfav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleIDfav);
            lokasiIDfav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lokasiIDFav);
            gajiIDfav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gajiIDFav);
            buttonViewOption = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FavoriteFragmentDetail favoriteFragmentDetail = new FavoriteFragmentDetail();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Favorit favorit = favoritList.get(getAdapterPosition());
//            bundle.putParcelable("favorit", favorit);
            favoriteFragmentDetail.setArguments(bundle);

            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) itemView.getContext();

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null);
//            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragmentFavorit, favoriteFragmentDetail);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }


    }
}
```

and

favorit_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/favorit_cardView"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_logoFav"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
            <!--android:background="@color/black_55"-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleIDfav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="63dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_below="@id/img_logoFav"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="Salesman Executive" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo_mapFav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/titleIDfav"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingBottom="1.7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                app2:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lokasiIDFav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo_mapFav"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/logo_mapFav"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:text="Siantan Hulu"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_gajiFav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                app2:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gajiIDFav"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_gajiFav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_gajiFav"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="Gaji: Rp. 5.000.000 - Rp. 10.000.000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewOptions"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="&#8942;"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your code seems fine with the recycler view I guess there is some problem with he anchor point you are passing through your ViewHolder in your adapter.

you should try to use call back methods in the clicklistener of your vu Holder. and use that call back in the activity where. you are attaching this adapter

Comment: what are you getting did you try debug?

Comment: thank you for trying to help, it turns out when I widen the layout, 3 dots are showing @Rizwanatta

Comment: has been successful, there is a small width error. Tq. @NaveenDew

Comment: use linear layout hierarchy scheme in the layout for adapter's inflation instead of Relative I mean in favourite.row

Comment: OK. Thank youu @Rizwanatta